# Import contacts into Office 365 public folder contacts folder by powershell

Tags: powershell, microsoft-office-365, import, public-folders, contacts

We've got a PBX that is able to synchronize its company phonebook with a shared contacts group from an office 365 public folder.

Now we're looking for a way to create an automated task which automagically imports contacts from a local csv-file into the public folders contacts subfolder.

We can add the contacts to the mailbox itself like this:

```
Import-Csv .\sql_export.csv|%{New-MailContact -Name $_.Name -DisplayName $_.Name -ExternalEmailAddress $_.ExternalEmailAddress -FirstName $_.FirstName -LastName $_.LastName}
```

But we couldn't find a way to specify where the new contacts should be stored.

Has this anyone allready successfully done or knows if this is even possible?

I think we're struggeling at the point how to navigate to the right folder.

Greetings
Steven

Comment: What have you tried so far. You wrote: "_I think we're strugg(e)ling at the point how to navigate to the right folder._" which implies that you have tried something. If you could post that snippet, you might be able to attract an answer.